# Use grails export plugin for multiple classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The grails export plugin is designed to export a single domain class. Is there a way to use the Grails export plugin to export a hierarchy of hasMany domain classes.  Could I do a join that creates a transient class or command object class.

For instance:

```
class Author {
  String name
  static hasMany = [books:Book]
}
class Book {
  String name
  static hasMany = [chapters:Chapter]
}
class Chapter {
  String name
  Integer pages
}
```

To create an export with each row having:

```
Author name, Book name, Chapter Name, pages
```

Comment: I may be able to create an expanded record as described [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/ANN-Export-plugin-0-7-released-td1835347.html) to accomplish what I want

Comment: Creating an expanded record as described in my comment above worked great.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used the expanded record approach described [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/ANN-Export-plugin-0-7-released-td1835347.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.